Trouble Defining Custom Connectors in Metamodel for <<EAUML::Master Document>> Elements
I'm having trouble defining some connectors in my metamodel. The idea is to create a set of custom connections to link <<EAUML::Master Document>> elements to other stereotyped elements.
So far, I've created multiple custom stereotyped connectors, but always using elements generalized from SysML1.4::Block as end-points. I've defined the metamodel similarly to the image below, but it is not working.
[
Is this possible? I've also tried to generalize a new stereotype from the <<EAUML::Master Document>>, but that was also not successful.
Does anyone know how to create this? Any help is appreciated.

Can you specify what your end goal is? Do you want to add additional relations to an existing stereotype?

The goal of these additions is to create a set of stereotyped elements and connectors to improve the management sections of the documentation. The idea is to have stereotyped elements that can be reused across multiple documents, which is why I am trying to define this specific behavior.
